# responsive image wrap around a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a bootstrap grid setup, inside a cell of the grid there is a div floating on right with a width of 250px; of course the text inside the cell follow the floating div contour and wrap around it; sometimes i add to the text some images that should fill the cell (100% width, img-responsive class as bootstrap do).
How can i have the image to stop at floating div if present on its side?
in my setup the image fill the width correctly, and if the floating is not present (or the image start below it) it is all correct, but if the image start beside it, it will go beneath it.
any suggestion?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure by what you mean, just wrap the image inside the div and you're ready to go?

Comment: I understande it is not easy to explain, here is a screenshot:
http://www.popeating.it/ss01.jpg
the image on the center got the img-responsive tag, so it fill its parent; in the same parent there's the right box (a div with float right), but the image go "over" it

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the image in a div as well and float it to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give a height and a width to the div that is floating right or set the image in a new parent div and try to align these next to each other.

Comment: the floating div have a width (but no height) i tried to wrap the image in  div with no success...